# Check all other checkboxes when one is checked

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have a form and group of checkboxes in it. (These checkboxes are dynamically created but I dont think it is important for this question). The code that generates them looks like this (part of the form):

```
<div id="ScrollCB">
    <input type="checkbox" name="ALL" value="checked" checked="checked">
    All (if nothing selected, this is default) <br>
    <c:forEach items="${serviceList}" var="service">
       <input type="checkbox" name="${service}" value="checked"> ${service} <br>
    </c:forEach>
</div>
```

What I want to do is control, whether the checkbox labeled "ALL" is checked and if yes - check all other checkboxes (and when unchecked, uncheck them all).

I tried doing this with javascript like this (found some tutorial), but it doesnt work (and Im real newbie in javascript, no wonder):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $ui.find('#ScrollCB').find('label[for="ALL"]').prev().bind('click',function(){
  $(this).parent().siblings().find(':checkbox').attr('checked',this.checked).attr('disabled',this.checked);
}); });
</script>
```

Could you tell me some simple approach how to get it work? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/crustyashish/6F4gc/)

[updated_demo](http://jsfiddle.net/crustyashish/6F4gc/2/)

**HTML:**

```
<label><input type="checkbox" name="sample" class="selectall"/> Select all</label>

<div id="checkboxlist">

    <label><input type="checkbox" name="sample[]"/>checkbox1</label><br />
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="sample[]"/>checkbox2</label><br />
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="sample[]"/>checkbox3</label><br />
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="sample[]"/>checkbox4</label><br />

</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$('.selectall').click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('div input').attr('checked', true);
    } else {
        $('div input').attr('checked', false);
    }
});
```

Comment: This works! However, if I do it once, it gets done. If I do, for example, check>uncheck>check, it doesnt work anymore... how come?

Comment: it works..even i tested like u mention in ur comment..check>uncheck>check

Comment: y, I know it works with your code... when I implement it, it only works the first time I use it with my code... I dont know why...

Comment: If it only works once, why is it a marked solution? Also it will add checked to any other element that is an input. Bad solution.

Comment: Still looks like all inputs to me.

Comment: I'd recommend using `.prop()` instead of `.attr()` to set the checked property of checkboxes, atleast with newer versions of jQuery.

Comment: The code did the same to me as with Smajl, however when I used .prop() instead of .attr() it still works after clicking a few times.

Comment: I had the same problem as @Smajl and it worked using prop()

Comment: I have used @Ashish's answer to expand it a little. See my answer below

Answer (score 4):

**HTML:**

```
<form>
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="selectall"/> Select all
</label>
<div id="checkboxlist">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="sample[]"/>checkbox1</label><br />
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="sample[]"/>checkbox2</label><br />
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="sample[]"/>checkbox3</label><br />
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="sample[]"/>checkbox4</label><br />
</div>
</form>
```

**JS:**

```
$('#selectall').click(function() {
    $(this.form.elements).filter(':checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wDnAd/1/

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to @Ashish, I have expanded it slightly to allow the "master" checkbox to be **automatically** checked or unchecked, if you manually tick all the sub checkboxes.

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/Fandango68/642d6q0b/2/)

**HTML**

```
<label><input type="checkbox" name="sample" class="selectall"/>Select all</label>

<div id="checkboxlist">
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="justone" name="sample[]"/>checkbox1</label><br/>
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="justone" name="sample[]"/>checkbox2</label><br />
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="justone" name="sample[]"/>checkbox3</label><br />
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="justone" name="sample[]"/>checkbox4</label><br />
</div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$('.selectall').click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('input:checkbox').prop('checked', true);
    } else {
        $('input:checkbox').prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```

And now add this to manage the master checkbox as well...

```
$("input[type='checkbox'].justone").change(function(){
    var a = $("input[type='checkbox'].justone");
    if(a.length == a.filter(":checked").length){
        $('.selectall').prop('checked', true);
    }
    else {
        $('.selectall').prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```

Comment: Correct Solution

Answer (score 3):

Add extra script according to your checkbox group:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function selectAll(source) {
    checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('colors[]');
    for(var i in checkboxes)
        checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
}
</script>
```

HTML Code:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="selectall" onClick="selectAll(this,'color')" />Select All
<ul>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="colors[]" value="red" />Red</li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="colors[]" value="blue" />Blue</li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="colors[]" value="green" />Green</li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="colors[]" value="black" />Black</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is the only answer that uses basic JavaScript... i.e. no jQuery.  Simple solutions for simple problems, people!  (Yes, I see the OP is trying to use jQuery, but the question title and body doesn't state so...  You never know who might end up here looking for a solution!)

Answer (score 1):

use this i hope to help you i know that this is a late answer but if any one come here again

```
$("#all").change(function () {
        $("input:checkbox").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Only in JavaScript with auto check/uncheck functionality of master when any child is checked/unchecked.

```
function FnCheckAll()
    {
        var ChildChkBoxes = document.getElementsByName("ChildCheckBox");
        for (i = 0; i < ChildChkBoxes.length; i++)
        {
            ChildChkBoxes[i].checked = document.forms[0].CheckAll.checked;
        }
    }
function FnCheckChild()
    {
        if (document.forms[0].ChildCheckBox.length > document.querySelectorAll('input[name="ChildCheckBox"]:checked').length)
            document.forms[0].CheckAll.checked = false;
        else
            document.forms[0].CheckAll.checked = true;
    }
```

Master CheckBox:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="CheckAll" id="CheckAll" onchange="FnCheckAll()" />
```

Child CheckBox:

````
<input type="checkbox" name="ChildCheckBox" id="ChildCheckBox" onchange="FnCheckChild()" value="@employee.Id" />```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery like so:

jQuery

```
$('[name="ALL"]:checkbox').change(function () {
   if($(this).attr("checked")) $('input:checkbox').attr('checked','checked');
   else $('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
});
```

A [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Agony/Dqnk5/4/).

Comment: `input:checkbox` and `:checkbox` are the same thing

Comment: Also post your code in your answer, probably why you got downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you would use a label when you have a name on the checkbox. Use that as the selector. Plus your code has no labels in the HTML markup so it will not find anything.

Here is the basic idea

```
$(document).on("click",'[name="ALL"]',function() {
    $(this).siblings().prop("checked",this.checked);
});
```

if there are other elements that are siblings, than you would beed to filter the siblings

```
$(document).on("click",'[name="ALL"]',function() {
    $(this).siblings(":checkbox").prop("checked",this.checked);
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mSyAU/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var selectedIds = [];
function toggle(source) {
    checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('ALL');
    for ( var i in checkboxes)
        checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
}
function addSelects() {

    var ids = document.getElementsByName('ALL');

    for ( var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
        if (ids[i].checked == true) {
            selectedIds.push(ids[i].value);
        }
    }
}
```

In HTML:

Master Check box `<input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle(this);">`

Other Check boxes `<input type="checkbox" name="ALL">`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the :first selector to find the first input and bind the change event to it. In my example below I use the :checked state of the first input to define the state of it's siblings. I would also suggest to put the code in the JQuery ready event.

```
    $('document').ready(function(){   
        $('#ScrollCB input:first').bind('change', function() {
            var first = $(this);
            first.siblings().attr('checked', first.is(':checked'));
        });
    });
```