# javascript checkbox check all

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I'm working on a check all button, but I'm a bit too unfamiliar with javascript to do this part.

Essentially, I have a checkbox at the top of the page, and when you check it, it goes through and changes a checkbox in each row of a table to be checked.

I've looked around at the similar questions and I know I have to use

```
~~~~.prop('checked', ...)
```

This is the checkbox which I would like to have check all the boxes in the table.

```
    <div class="disc-opt" style="float:left">
        Adjust All            
        <div class="make-switch">
            <input type="checkbox" class="create-adjustments"  />
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is the table row layout.

```
<tr class="<?= $data['adjusted'] ? "success" : "" ?>">
    <td>
       Stuff
    </td>
    <td><?= $data['products_name'] ?></td>
    <td><?= $data['total_final_quantity'] ?></td>
    <td><?= $data['total_onhand'] ?></td>
    <td><?= $data['difference'] ?> </td>
    <td><?= $data['difference_cost'] ?></td>
    <!-- The Checkbox to be changed -->
    <td class = "Adjustbox">
        <?php if(!$data['adjusted']): ?>
            <div class="make-switch">
                <input type="checkbox" name="adjust_products[]"
                                    value="<?= $products_id ?>">
            </div>
        <?php else: ?>
            Adjustment Complete
        <?php endif; ?>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Edit: Here's what I'm currently working with(I'm not sure if this is really poorly set up, it's from a bunch of old code I've never touched before today). I've made some edits in the code above as well.

```
function createAdjustments()
{
    if($("#create-adjustments").is(':checked'))
    {
        //turn all on
    } else {
        //turn all off
    }
}

$('#create-adjustments').change(function(e)
{
    createAdjustments();
});

$('#create-adjustments').trigger('change');
```

I've been able to access the element in the table row via the document.ready function, but I couldn't get anything to work when I checked the checkbox.

Here's a picture of what I'm trying to do:[image: Checkbox on top left is the one that I want to check to check all in the table.]

I'm trying to make it so that when I check the checkbox on the top left, it goes through the table and checks all of the checkboxes in the right column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving it using this.

```
if($("#create-adjustments").is(':checked'))
    {
        $("tr").find("td.box").find("div").find("div").prop('class', "switch-on switch-animate");
    } else {
        $("tr").find("td.box").find("div").find("div").prop('class', "switch-off switch-animate");

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19658068/check-all-other-checkboxes-when-one-is-checked) I did a similar thing earlier and this did the trick for me. Pretty much, you create a div with all your input boxes and say to mark all of them as checked if the main one is clicked.

HTML:

```
<label><input type="checkbox" name="sample" class="selectall"/> Select all</label>

<div id="checkboxlist">

    <label><input type="checkbox" name="sample[]"/>checkbox1</label><br />
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="sample[]"/>checkbox2</label><br />
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="sample[]"/>checkbox3</label><br />
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="sample[]"/>checkbox4</label><br />

</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$('.selectall').click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('div input').attr('checked', true);
    } else {
        $('div input').attr('checked', false);
    }
});
```

Comment: Optimum would be to add a code example. The problem with links is that the go away while your written summary will stay. Link only is valid as comment, but not as answer.

Comment: @AlexeyAyzin: I suggest adding a code snippet, as suggested by Thomas. Your question is borderline link-only at the moment.

Comment: @Matt Is this any better? Sorry took me a while to get back to it

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about `~~~~.prop('checked', ...)` , then you're talking about jQuery.

In that case if you want to check a checkbox you would want to provide an `ID` or  `class`. If you don't want  , well :

```
$(".make-switch input:checkbox:first").prop('checked',true)
```

Comment: I just added some information up top, I'm struggling to get it to work still.

Answer (score 0):

```
<label><input type="checkbox" name="sample" class="selectall"/> Select all</label>

<div id="checkboxlist">

    <label><input type="checkbox" name="sample[]"/>checkbox1</label><br />
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="sample[]"/>checkbox2</label><br />
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="sample[]"/>checkbox3</label><br />
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="sample[]"/>checkbox4</label><br />

</div>

$('.selectall').click(function() {     
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {        
        $('#checkboxlist input[type="checkbox"').prop('checked', true);
    } else {
        $('#checkboxlist input[type="checkbox"').prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/67bszw0h/)