# how can i selectAll checkboxes when i check on contacts in my case ?!! ionic 2

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ionic2

```js
  selectAll() {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.groupedContacts.length; i++) {
      for(var j = 0; j < this.groupedContacts[i].length; j++)
        this.groupedContacts[i][j].selected = this.selectedAll;
    }
  }

  checkIfAllSelected() {
    for(var i = 0; i < this.groupedContacts.length; i++){
      this.groupedContacts[i].every(function(item:any){
        let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
          message: item.selected == true,
          duration: 3000,
          position: 'bottom'
        });
        return  item.selected == true;
      })
    }
  }

  
  synchroContactSelected() {
```

```html
<ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="selectedAll" (ionChange)="selectAll()" >contacts</ion-checkbox>
      <ion-item-group *ngFor="let group of groupedContacts">

        <!-- alphabet
              <ion-item-divider id="scroll-letter-{{group.letter}}" light>{{group.letter}}</ion-item-divider>
            -->
        <ion-item *ngFor="let cont of group.contacts;" text-wrap>
          <ion-label> {{cont.prenom_user}} {{cont.nom_user}}
            <p *ngIf="cont.mobile_perso != ''"> {{cont.mobile_perso | phone }}
              <br *ngIf="cont.email_perso != ''" /> {{cont.email_perso}}
            </p>
            <p *ngIf="cont.mobile_pro != '' && cont.mobile_perso == '' "> {{cont.mobile_pro | phone }}
              <br *ngIf="cont.email_pro != ''" /> {{cont.email_pro}}
            </p>
            <p *ngIf="cont.tel_domicile != '' && cont.mobile_pro == '' && cont.mobile_perso == '' "> {{cont.tel_domicile | phone }} </p>
            <p *ngIf="cont.tel_pro != '' && cont.tel_domicile == '' && cont.mobile_pro == '' && cont.mobile_perso == '' "> {{cont.tel_pro | phone }} </p>
          </ion-label> 
          
          <ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="cont.selected" (ionChange)="synchronizeContact(cont, $event)" (ionChange)="checkIfAllSelected()"  ></ion-checkbox>
        </ion-item>

      </ion-item-group>

    </ion-col>
```

i tried to selectAll my checkboxes by using selectAll and checkIfAllSelected() but it don't work 
In my .TS i have just groupedContacts which has an array of groups.
do you have any idéa to résolve my problem ?! thank you

Answer (score 0):

Someone has already ask some related to what you've asked, to see it [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19658068/check-all-other-checkboxes-when-one-is-checked)

The following code is from the one of the Answers that was given as right:

**HTML:**

```
<label><input type="checkbox" name="sample" class="selectall"/> Select all</label>

<div id="checkboxlist">
   <label><input type="checkbox" name="sample[]"/>checkbox1</label><br />
   <label><input type="checkbox" name="sample[]"/>checkbox2</label><br />
   <label><input type="checkbox" name="sample[]"/>checkbox3</label><br />
   <label><input type="checkbox" name="sample[]"/>checkbox4</label><br />
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$('.selectall').click(function() {
if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $('div input').attr('checked', true);
} else {
    $('div input').attr('checked', false);
}
});
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I already saw this post, but it does not apply to my case here !!
thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think one solution could be this :

Here you're looping : `*ngFor="let cont of group.contacts;"` trought contacts, you can edit this in: `*ngFor="let cont of group.contacts;let i = index"`.
Then in your .ts create an boolean array (group.contacts.length). This array is tha array of checked for your checkbox, then here:

```
<ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="cont.selected" (ionChange)="synchronizeContact(cont, $event)" (ionChange)="checkIfAllSelected()"  ></ion-checkbox>
```

add the checked

```
  <ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="cont.selected" (ionChange)="synchronizeContact(cont, $event);checkIfAllSelected()" [checked]="myBoolArr[i]" ></ion-checkbox>
```

So you can inizialize the array all to true maybe when this fuction is called checkIfAllSelected(), and the result will be all checkboxes selected.

Then you can change the array values.

I hope this can help you, but it need this array.Sorry also for my english